# Line graph in excel showing number of orders by customer by week

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a simple spreadsheet with 3 columns:

```
customer,orders,weeknumber
```

e.g.

```
dave,1,20
dave,7,21
dave,0,22
dave,15,23
john,4,18
john,4,19
john,0,20
john,8,21
john,15,22
```

I would like to show a line graph with the X axis showing the week numbers and the Y axis showing the number of orders. There would then be 2 lines (one for each customer) showing their number of orders per week.

If I try and use a simple line chart in Excel then it's not using the correct columns for the two axis and I am getting lost!

UPDATE:

I've been using the "Select data source" page to try and alter what shows in on the two axes. I can do this (so date goes on X and orders on Y) but I can't then get multiple customers to show as individual rows

Comment: @Cfinley I've been using the "Select data source" page to try and alter what shows in on the two axes.  I can do this (so date goes on X and orders on Y) but I can't then get multiple customers to show as individual rows

Comment: Go ahead and edit your question with that information and anything else that you think would help people help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-arrange your data so that you have week numbers as column headings - as you wish to have them along the x-axis.
Then it is simple to set customers as row headings, and fill in the orders as numbers in that matrix.

Select the entire matrix, then play around with the settings for your chart. I'm sure you can find your way ;-)